# DokuWiki live preview like in Stack Exchange software?

Tags: wiki, dokuwiki

Is there a plugin for DokuWiki which gives a live preview during editing like the one used by the Stack Exchange applications, **including** live preview of math formulas ([jsMath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JsMath) with [MathJax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax)), as in [MathOverflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathOverflow)? If not, is there other wiki software which supports that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the plugin [fckglite](http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin%3afckglite%3a):

> fckglite editor for dokuwiki does WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editing

Search for *WYSIWYG* and *wikis* or checkout the wiki matrices at:

- [WikiMatrik](http://www.wikimatrix.org)
- [Wiki Software Comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software)